# Dates returned from database and put it in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an ajax function that return a date and i can't push this date...

```
var dates = [];

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "agenda.php?action=getData",
        success: function(data){
            dates.push(data);
        }
    });

    console.log(dates); // here prints [] .... =/ .... and i made other test i put var dates = [] outside of $(document).ready... and nothing
```

Comment: What does `agenda.php?action=getData` return?

Comment: return simple date like 2014/12/20.... and if i can make it work... i will return an json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the ajax call is asynchronous, execution continues immediately.  Therefore dates is still [] when execution makes it to the console.log.

You will need to do your processing inside of the callback function that you pass to $.ajax's success.